# Navigation List Attribute filled with empty objects (except for the ID)

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

Well this should be an easy one (but apperently not for me).
I have an AJAX routine sending all my data in JSON format to the controller. Everything is perfect and the Model object attributes, back at the controller, are being correctly filled with all the data i've sent from the View. Except that one of those attributes is a List of Objects and for which, from the View, i'm sending only the IDs of the objects that should populate the list.
  What is happening is that the List attribute of the Model object is being filled with instances that got only the ID information, and what i needed it to do was to load all the other attributes using that ID present in the List sent from the View.

Some code to illustrate:

```
        // Creating Documento Json Object
        var docs = { "IDDocumento": "" };

        // Creating Lote Json Object
        var lote = { 
            "IDLote": "", 
            "Numero": "", 
            "Documentos": []
        };

        // Set Lote's Values
        lote.IDLote             = $("#IDLote").val();
        lote.Numero             = $("#Numero").val();

        $.each($('input[name="Documento"]:checked'), function (index, element) {
            var temp = $(element).attr('id').replace('Documento_', '').trim();

            // Set Documento individual Value
            docs.IDDocumento = temp; // << HERE IM FILLING WITH THE DESIRED OBJECT ID

            // adding to Lote.Documentos List Naviagtion Attribute
            lote.Documentos.push(docs);
            docs = { "IDDocumento": "" };
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: '/Lote/Edit',
            data: JSON.stringify(lote),
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json;',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.Success == "1") {
                    window.location.href = "/Lote/Index";
                }
                else {
                  //Take care of the exception...
                }
            }
        });
```

And the class from which the above view is strongly typed, is:

```
public class Lote
{
    [Key]
    public int IDLote { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(20)]
    public string Numero {get;set;}

    public List<Documento> Documentos { get; set; }
```

Finally, the class for the Navigation attribute object type:

```
public class Documento
{
    [Key]
    public int IDDocumento { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(60)]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    public List<Lote> Lotes { get; set; }
}
```

Any help?